# Using specific types based on typeof inside generic function

Tags: c#, generics

I want to have a generic function for a few types such as long, TimeSpan and DateTime.

```
public static T Parse<T>(string text)
{
    T store;

    if(typeof(T) == typeof(TimeSpan)
        store = (T)((object) new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0));
    else
    {
        T.tryParse(text, out store);
    }
    return store;
}
```

Is there a better way than the double T/object cast?

The t.tryParse does not compile, how can I accomplish something similar?

Comment: What is the compilation error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It feels to me like it would be better to have an overloaded method in this case. There's nothing really generic about calling `TryParse` - `Int32.TryParse` is an entirely different method from `Int64.TryParse` etc. That will get you away from the double cast, too (which I agree is ugly, but unfortunately hard to avoid). It also means you'd be specifying which types you can genuinely support.

One alternative is to use a `Dictionary<Type, Func<string, object>>`:

```
// Add some error checking, obviously :)
Func<string, object> parser = parsers[typeof(T)];
return (T) parser(form.Text);
```

then set up the dictionary with something like:

```
static readonly Dictionary<Type, Func<string, object>> parsers = 
    new Dictionary<Type, Func<string, object>>()
{
    { typeof(int), x => int.Parse(x) },
    { typeof(TimeSpan) x => new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0) },
    ...
}
```

If you want to use `TryParse` instead of `Parse`, you'll need to create your own delegate type due to the use of out parameters (which aren't supported in `Func`/`Action`). Life becomes a little harder at that point.

As an aside, why are you using an `out` parameter instead of a return value?

Comment: The out in the Parse<T> function was to match the out in the TryParse call. My question only had an except of the real code that does return a bool that represent the outcome of TryParse.
I will shortly look into the answer, thanks.

Comment: Removed the out in response to your question to keep my question focused.